# pyspark.sql module error: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions

Tags: pyspark, jupyter, apache-spark-sql

```py
df = spark.read.parquet('xxx')
tmstmp = df['timestamp']

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Singapore")

time_df = spark.createDataFrame([('tmstmp',)], ['unix_time'])
time_df.select(from_unixtime('unix_time').alias('ts')).collect()

df['timestamp'] = time_df

spark.conf.unset("spark.sql.session.timeZone")
```

there is an error at this line:

```
time_df.select(from_unixtime('unix_time').alias('ts')).collect()
```

with the exception error msg:

> Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

The exception that you are receiving is pretty clear in itself.
You have a cluster with two or more nodes. The server/node from where you submitted this command(master) has different version of python than your other nodes(worker).

Possible solution:

- Bump up your worker nodes python version or set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` env to python3.7 installation.
- change your  driver python version to match worker nodes version.